# Change item height in famous-flex list

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I have a list in a `FlexScrollView`.
I'm selecting an item in the list according to some logic, and I need the selected item to expand. Since a change in height won't be noticed by `famo.us` I'm looking for a way to make it work. Any ideas?

So far I have tried a css transition that occurs when the selected surface gets selected, but of course this doesn't change the position of the other items because of how `famo.us` works.

I also tried to add a `StateModifier` as a datasource (wrapped with `RenderNode`) instead of directly adding the surface. I then tried to make the transition happen via the `StateModifier` I created but it doesn't seem to move the surface at all, even the completion function of `setTransform` isn't being called.

**Update:**
I managed to get the item to animate via the `RenderNode`, but the other items stay put and get drawn over by my expanding item. Added the question to `famous-flex` github page https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex/issues/53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using setSize animation instead of setTransform. For some reason my eyes insisted that the docs don't say anything about animating size.